# HTML5 audio not playing in iPad

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I want to start my audio after video started to play. Please refer my html code in below

```
<audio id="my_audio" >
<source src="${audioPath}" type="audio/mpeg" >
</audio>
```

Please refer my javascript code in below

```
    var isAudioStarted = false;
    var video = document.getElementById('my_video');    
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {  
        if((video.currentTime > 1) && isAudioStarted == false){             
             var myAudio = document.getElementById('my_audio');
             myAudio.load();
             myAudio.play();
             if(myAudio.played){
                 console.log("Audio start to play");
             }

            isAudioStarted = true;
        }

     }, false);
```

This code is not play the audio in iPad. But it successfully pass the if(myAudio.played) condition and print "Audio start to play".

I dont know what is the error. Please anyone guide me to fix the error.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not allow to play Audio Files without an touch or click event by the user.